# ACTION_CALL_BUTTON intent crashes when used in input method

Tags: android

when i use this in an activity, it works.

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON);
startActivity(intent);
```

but when i use it in an input method (i'm using the anySoftKeyboard source code), it crashes.

any idea why?

Comment: add here more code also code of input method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there isn't much more code except a few more intents that do work and the AnySoftKeyboard source code.

https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard

eventually i figured it out.

i was missing:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```